# Upload jupyter notebook to Google Cloud Datalab?

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-storage, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-datalab

I have a machine learning notebook that I want to upload to Datalab so I can train my model faster. My training data is not large and is sitting in a Google Cloud Storage bucket, accessible to Datalab. My model is costly to train though so I want to use cloud compute resources. It seems if I could  get my notebook into Datalab, I could read in the data from the GCS bucket location instead of from local storage and I'd be all set for fast model training!

On the Datalab interface there is an 'Upload' button which does nothing when I click it.

Many thanks for your guidance!

Comment: You will find the following post [A Gentle Introduction To Google Cloud Platform For Machine Learning Practice](http://ekababisong.org/google-cloud-platform-machine-learning-practice/) useful.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed the click target for the upload button is a little misleading. If you click the icon it doesn't work, you need to click on the word, look at the click target highlighted in the screenshot below. Does this work for you? If not, what browser are you using?

[image]